# Firestore query not working when i include "where equal to" its gives the error i.eQuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i add whereEqualTo..its give an error that QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference.Without whereEqualTo the code works fine. In my firestore console i have the needed fields correctly spelt.It seems the problem seems to be with "whereEqualTo".

```
CollectionReference statusHistory = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts");
Query firstQuery = statusHistory.orderBy("status",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("status","Finished").limit(3);
            firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {


                        if (isFirstPageLoad) {

                            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                        }


                        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                String blogPostId = doc.getDocument().getId();

                                BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostId);

                                if (isFirstPageLoad) {

                                    blog_list.add(blogPost);

                                } else {
                                    blog_list.add(0, blogPost);


                                }

                                blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }


                        }
                        isFirstPageLoad = false;


                    }else{




                    }
                }





            });




03-28 16:26:36.215 18903-18903/com.example.hpenvy17.betpro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.hpenvy17.betpro, PID: 18903
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.hpenvy17.betpro.Tab3Fragment$2.onEvent(Tab3Fragment.java:114)
                                                                             at com.example.hpenvy17.betpro.Tab3Fragment$2.onEvent(Tab3Fragment.java:110)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevd.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

03-28 16:26:36.244 1197-3541/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build

Comment: show your logcat.

Comment: logcat has been added

Comment: Please add your database structure.